# How do I do a DB Upsert for Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use `upsert` with MongoDB and `pymongo` to add about 10 data items, but only 1 item is added.
How can I add 10 cases?

Of course it is possible to get 10 cases using `insert`, but I want to use `upsert` because I want to add the data when it is updated.

Thanks.

```
url = 'https://watcher.guru/news/category/metaverse'

def db_set(self):
    db_url = 'mongodb://pyton:pyton@192.168.0.2:27017'
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(db_url)
    db = client.blog
    collection = db.crypto

    return collection

def article_parse(self):
    url_lists: list =  self.article()
    collection =  self.db_set()

    for url in url_lists:
        respon = self.response(url)
        soup = self.soup(respon)
        title = soup.find('div', {'id': 'primary'}).find('h1').text
        url = url
        texts = soup.find('div', {'class': 'entry-content'}).text.strip()
        print(texts)
        print('---------------------')

        collection.update_many({}, {'$set':{'title': title, 'url': url, 'text': texts}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: `collection.update_many({}, ...` will update all documents, and in this case with each identical `'$set'`.  Since you update with the same fields, I'm guessing that only the last `url` fields/values remain at the end of the `for` loop.  I.e., you update and overwrite every doc over and over again so only the last update persists.

Comment: That was true. Thank you.

I have made it so that the differences are retrieved by pandas and saved to the DB.